# Remove File .java Maven Project

Tags: java, maven, archetypes

I have a Java Maven Project generated through archetype and would like to delete a .java file in an automated way. Is there any way in Maven to do it?

Comment: If you don't want that file, you can create your own archetype. It is not very difficult.

Comment: Sorry, I do not speak Italian.

Comment: I use it to rename the project file, after which I want a way to automatically delete.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot follow you. If you want a different template than the standard archetype, just create your own archetype and use it for your projects. Have a look at the maven archetype plugin.